# Configuring TCPDF for use on local server with MAMP

Tags: php, tcpdf

I wish to use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) so have downloaded the code and am having trouble using it.

I work on Mac locally using MAMP.

My project is stored in:

> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-project-title

I place the whole `tcpdf` folder in my project so it's location is:

> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-project-title/tcpdf

I found a file `tcpdf_include.php` in the examples directory so I pulled it out and placed it also in the `tcpdf` folder:

> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-project-title/tcpdf/tcpdf_include.php

So I wasn't sure if this was right but it seemed so. I then referenced `tcpdf_include.php` in my script: `require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf_include.php');` and it found the file all good.

Now I was confused as to how exactly this was working. I ran an example and got nothing and error log states:

> [04-Nov-2015 16:27:36 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'TCPDF' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-project-title/scripts/myscript.php on line 15

... so it seems like it's just not running the script. I went to the config file to attempt to edit some stuff there.

I changed the following in the config file:

```
define ('K_PATH_MAIN',  '/MAMP/htdocs/my-project-title/tcpdf/');
define ('K_PATH_URL', 'http://localhost:8888/my-project-title/tcpdf/');
```

These are now inline with how my project is set up. But I'm still getting the above error when I try to run the script.

What am I missing are there any examples of how to properly configure TCPDF?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Store the script you are trying to run in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-project-title`, eg. `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-project-title/test.php`
2. In that script, just do `require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');` (I'm assuming the `tcpdf` folder is still sitting here: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my-project-title/tcpdf`)
3. You should then be able to instantiate an instance of the `TCPDF` class.

You shouldn't need to worry about anything else - it should just work. If it doesn't, try creating a fresh folder in your `htdocs` folder, drop a fresh copy of `tcpdf` in there and try again, just in case you've moved something in your current version that is messing things up.

To be clear, this is what `test.php` should contain:

```
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF();
```

Good luck!